# Is a set closed with respect to $ f$ also closed under $ f^{-1}$

Tags: functions

Let $f : E \to E$ be a one-to-one mapping.
Let $A$ be a subset of $E$. $A$ is closed under $f$.
Is $A$ closed under $f^{-1}$ ?

I know this is true when A is finite but is it also true when A is infinite ? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "$A$ is closed under $f$"? What is the link with field-theory?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake I will edit it now.

Comment: I mean that if $x$ is in $A$ then $f(x)$ is in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, say $f(x) = x/2$. Then $f([0,1]) \subseteq [0,1]$ but $f^{-1}(x) = 2x$ and $f^{-1}([0,1]) = [0,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

No, take $E=\Bbb{Z}$, $A=\Bbb{N}$ and $f:n\mapsto n+1$.